# Magento 2.1.16 - Search only returning 1 page of results

Tags: magento-2.1, search, catalogsearch

Since **updating to 2.1.16** our **search results** now only return **one page** of **30 results**.

There is no option to view **other results or other pages** of search results.

Where can I investigate further?

Thanks.